# Selenium Xpath Not Matching Items

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use Selenium's Xpath ability to be able to find an set of elements.  I have used FirePath on FireFox to create and test the Xpath that I have come up with and that is working just fine but when I use the Xpath in my c# test with Selenium nothing is returned.

```
var MiElements = this._driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='context-menu-item' and descendant::div[text()='Action Selected Jobs']]"));
```

and the Html looks like this:-
[image]
Can Anyone please point me right as everything that I have read the web says to me that this Xpath is correct.

Thanking you all in-advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the selenium IDE (for firefox) to generate the commands for you?

Answer (score 1):

Please post the *actual* HTML, so we can simply "drop it in" into a HTML file and try it ourselves but I noticed that there is a trailing space at the end of the class name:

```
<div title="Actions Selected Jobs." class="context-menu-item " .....
```

So force XPath to strip the trailing spaces first:

```
var MiElements = this._driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[normalize-space(@class)='context-menu-item' and descendant::div[text()='Action Selected Jobs']]"));
```

Comment: Sorry the html is generated dynamically by both the server & javascripts on the the client.

Comment: Cheers Arran After looking at that space you have highlighted I have added the space into my Xpath and It's resolved the problem it not finds the Elements.  

Strange however that Firepath in Firefox didn't care.

Comment: @ToxicBlotch All that said, you could consider using `By.cssSelector("div.context-menu-item[title='Action Selected Jobs']")` if it matches your requirements (it's slightly different from tehe XPath you have there). CSS selectors (or `By.className()`) are usually the way to go if you need to handle classes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you don't take into consideration the time that the elements need to load and you look for them when they aren't yet "searchable". **UPDATE** I skipped examples regarding this issue. See *Slanec's* comment.

Anyway, Selenium recommends to avoid searching by xpath whenever it is possible, because of being slower and more "fragile".
You could find your element like this:

```
//see the method code below
WebElement div = findDivByTitle("Action Selected Jobs");

//example of searching for one (first found) element
if (div != null) {
    WebElement myElement = div.findElement(By.className("context-menu-item"));
}

......

//example of searching for all the elements
if (div != null) {
    WebElement myElement = div.findElements(By.className("context-menu-item-inner"));
}

//try to wrap the code above in convenient method/s with expressive names 
//and separate it from test code

......

WebElement findDivByTitle(final String divTitle) {
    List<WebElement> foundDivs = this._driver.findElements(By.tagName("div"));

    for (WebElement div : foundDivs) {
        if (element.getAttribute("title").equals(divTitle)) {
        return element;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is approximate code (based on your explanation), you should adapt it better to your purposes. Again, remember to take the load time into account and to separate your utility code from the test code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's a lot of code for one XPath expression (or a single CSS selector in this particular case) with no additional benefit (there's no handling of the async load problem you mentioned). If you're afraid of loading times of asynchronously-loaded elements, the preferred way is to use Implicit/Explicit wait. While this will work, I am not convinced of its usefullness and benefits. While XPaths might sometimes get tricky (mostly with `class` handling as in this case) and are slow on IE6+8 (what's _not_ slow there?), they are often the right tool for the job when used properly and not overused.

Comment: Totally agree about what you say about the loading times. I mentioned it for just in case ToxicBlotch didn't count with that.

Comment: As for the code (and as I mentioned) it is approximate. Adjusting it to your needs, will likely make it shorter. Besides, the proper way would be to make it as generic as possible and put into a separate utility package: thus it will serve you more than once. Also, it's not about the amount of code, it's rather about it's quality :) I try to avoid searching by xpath: it's less expressive and really sensitive, especially with generated html.